# water simulation -Move water upward along a slope

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to make a simulation where water move upward along a topography opposite to what it does under normal gravity. I dont want just to water behave like smoke and go straight upward but to behave like fluid and crawl upward along slope
can any one help

Answer (score 2):

In the Scene settings, switch off Gravity by unticking the checkbox. This will enable the Gravity settings in the Fluid Domain Settings. You can then adjust the gravity such that the 'uphill' becomes 'downhill' and the water naturally flows uphill.

Note that this depends on the topology being such that the water will naturally flow in the desired direction - eg, up an indented riverbed. If the situation is more complicated you may need to resort to other methods to 'Guide' the water along the path but this would risk making the motion less natural.

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion.I tried  but water mives straight up in space without staying on the inclined effector.

Comment: Without seeing your setup it’s difficult to comment. However, if you’ve just set the gravity from -9.8 to +9.8 then it will fall straight up. If you adjust the gravity to point into the “hill” at a carefully set angle then you should get it to run uphill. eg, if you have a 45degree slope in the X direction then setting gravity to -6,0,-4 will point it such that water will run up the hill (think about where the normal of the surface would point and angle gravity slighly ‘above’ that).